# My Joins are greyed out and I need help to understand why

Tags: sql, join

I can't see why this join is not working.

I am working on the Northwind database

```
SELECT 
    OrderDetails.OrderID, 
    OrderDetails.ProductID, 
    OrderDetails.UnitPrice, 
    OrderDetails.Quantity, 
    OrderDetails.Discount, 
    Products.ProductName, 
FROM
    OrderDetails
LEFT JOIN
    Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID;
GO
```

I get the error message

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Comment: remove the comma after ...ProductName

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

There was an extra comma after the last field that I removed.  I also added aliases to make it easier to read.

```
SELECT
    O.OrderID, 
    O.ProductID, 
    O.UnitPrice, 
    O.Quantity, 
    O.Discount,
    O.ProductName
FROM OrderDetails O
Left Join Products P ON O.ProductID = P.ProductID
```

You can also run the following code statements one by one to see if you get an error when running any.  This will help to troubleshoot if all columns and tables exist.  Also make sure that you're connected to the correct database.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderDetails
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products

SELECT TOP 1 OrderID FROM OrderDetails
SELECT TOP 1 ProductID FROM OrderDetails
SELECT TOP 1 UnitPrice FROM OrderDetails
SELECT TOP 1 Quantity FROM OrderDetails
SELECT TOP 1 Discount FROM OrderDetails
SELECT TOP 1 ProductName FROM OrderDetails

SELECT TOP 1 ProductID FROM Products
```